# SoundWire Server application does not launch

Tags: 18.04, error-handling

I saved SoundWire_Server_linux64.tar.gz in my Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop from georgielabs.net and unzipped it using the system Terminal. I then went to the folder and tried to open the application. I get the error message:- "There was an error launching the application".
The SoundWire App in my Android is unable to link to the SoundWire Server automatically and I am unable to manually enter the server ID as the SoundWire Server did not launch. 
What do I do now please?

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked pretty long ago. But still providing an answer for those who have this issue.

You need to install `pavucontrol` and `libportaudio2` packages.

`sudo apt install pavucontrol libportaudio2`

If it still doesn't work, try launching the app from terminal to know more details as to what causes the application to not launch. If there's any missing package install it.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get upgrade` to upgrade the installed packages. The phone and PC should be in the same local area network to connect.